# jquery select option selected with default value

Tags: jquery

I would like to ask a little help. I have a little jquery code:
I have some select option HTML tag, but if i choose the last one, with Jquery I made visible an input text, It works very well, but if I choose the last one for default value (check="checked"), it doesont work.
Here is my code:

```
<select id="szab">
  <option>Choose Your Name</option>
  <option>Frank</option>
  <option>George</option>
  <option selected="selected">Last</option>
</select>
```

And here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#szab').change(function(){
        if($('#szab option:selected').text() == "Last"){
         $('#Last').css("visibility","visible").css("height","auto");
        }else{
         $('#Last').css("visibility","hidden").css("height","0");
        }
    })
});
```

what should I change?
Thanks in advance.
B

Comment: Just trigger change after: `$('#szab').change(function(){ .... }).trigger('change');`

Comment: Yes, thanks, I had seen and I corrected, but not is my main problem.

Comment: If you try this code in your browser if you load this page you don't see hidden part, but if you choose from the list it works

Comment: Yes, I changed, sorry

Comment: no, it not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trigger your event on load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#szab').change(function(){
        if($('#szab option:selected').text() == "Last"){
         $('#Last').css("visibility","visible").css("height","auto");
        }else{
         $('#Last').css("visibility","hidden").css("height","0");
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```